# Why do I get Cannot resolve symbol 'CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY'?

Tags: android, android-studio, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-stickers

Why do I get `Cannot resolve symbol 'CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY' if I have set this on my build grade:

```
def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".provider.StickerContentProvider"
        manifestPlaceholders =
                [contentProviderAuthority: contentProviderAuthority]
        // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
        buildConfigField("String", "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY", "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
```

And this on the manifest file:

```xml
<provider
            android:name=".provider.StickerContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ" />
```

Thanks! <3

Comment: They should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Go in the build.gradle file and paste in android

```
aaptOptions {
        noCompress "webp"
    }
```

and after this paste this in defaultconfig

```
def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".StickerContentProvider"
        // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
        manifestPlaceholders =
                [contentProviderAuthority: contentProviderAuthority]
        // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
        buildConfigField("String",
                "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY",
                "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
```